# How to filter combined values using ag-grid in-built column filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I have a column definition like this. I am combining more than one value to show as a title in title column. But the in built column filtering is returning empty rows whenever i type something in the column filter. What am i doing wrong here. Why column filtering is not working for combined values. How to achieve this.

```
title: {
                minWidth: 90,
                cellClassRules: {
                    'completedFieldClass': function(params) {
                        return params.value && params.value.completed;
                    }
                },
                cellStyle: getCellStyle,
                cellRenderer: function(params) {
                    var prqId = params.data.id;
                    var type = (!!params.data.type) ? params.data.type.value + ': ' : '';
                    var desc = (!!params.data.id) ? '- '+params.data.description : '';

                    if(!!params.data.access){
                        var concatTitle = '<a>';
                        concatTitle = concatTitle + '<strong>'+type+'</strong><span>'+params.value.value+'</span>';
                        concatTitle = concatTitle + '<span>'+desc+'</span></a>';
                        return concatTitle;
                    } else{
                        var concatTitle = '<span class="notprint">';
                        concatTitle = concatTitle + '<strong>'+type+'</strong><span>'+params.value.value+'</span>';
                        concatTitle = concatTitle + '<span>'+desc+'</span></span>';
                        return concatTitle;
                        //return '<span class="notprint">' + modValue + ''+ configDesc +'</span>';
                    }
                },
                sortable: false
            },
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the built in filters will look at the cell value - to override this you can either write your own [Custom Filter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/), or use a valueGetter.

In your particular case it might be easiest to use a valueGetter, as follows:

```
...
cellStyle: getCellStyle,
valueGetter: function(params) {
    // for example - you should extract your field logic and use it here too
    return params.data.id + params.data.access; 
},
cellRenderer: function(params) {
...
```